# How to read data from S3 using aws role

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am using Pyspark 3.1 locally to access data in s3 using AWS access key, password, and "s3a" protocol, it is working fine. I want to use AWS role instead of AWS keys. Can someone tell me the syntax to use this?

I have tried below code but it was giving an error:

```
 spark_context._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.s3a.aws.credentials.provider", "org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.auth.AssumedRoleCredentialProvider")

spark_context._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.s3a.assumed.role.arn", "arn:aws:iam::2:role/admin-admin-admin")
```

I am getting error as:

```
Unable to load AWS credentials from environment variables (AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID (or AWS_ACCESS_KEY) and AWS_SECRET_KEY
```

Thanks,
XI

Comment: Did you manage to solve?

Answer (score 0):

Your EMR instances should already have a role attached to them. When you create the cluster you specify the role to use. So figure out what cluster you are using the role attached to it, and then add the appropriate IAM policy to that role. In fact, I wouldn't expect that you would need to have your code assume a role without a very good reason.

If you are using IAM tokens in production you are doing something wrong.

[image]

For more information about roles in EMR and on the underlying ec2 instances please see these docs: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ManagementGuide/emr-iam-role-for-ec2.htmlthis

Comment: No ,not  run EMR, I am reading S3 in my pyspark program and How to give role to read this s3 bucket

Comment: @Xi12 Your pyspark cluster assuming it's running in EMR it already has that a role assumed on the instances by default.

Comment: @Xi12 Take note of the EC2 instance profile role above.

Comment: and on local how would you run it without AWS?

Comment: @Xi12 You would have used `aws configure` to add your access key to your local profile.

Comment: Then the aws sdk will use your regular user permissions to perform those requests.

Comment: if I dont specify AWS credentials in pyspark, It will thrown an error as 
Unable to load AWS credentials from environment variables (AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID (or AWS_ACCESS_KEY) and AWS_SECRET_KEY

Comment: I think I need to write AWS ACCESS and KEYS  to access S3, it wouldnty automatically read from aws configure

Comment: @Xi12 One of the things aws hammers into people is don't put access keys on the ec2 instance. You get a role automatically attached to them. What's the rest of the context surrounding the assumed role and where does that come from?

Comment: So I read from s3 bucket, perform transformations, and put it in another bucket. I have used aws keys  to do this operation . Now I want to avoid  keys and use roles to perform this operation

Comment: Exactly. I don't know what you are doing with your hadoop configuration, but if you are using normal s3 calls you shouldn't need what you have there. Please take a look at these [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ManagementGuide/emr-iam-role-for-ec2.html)

Comment: I see your point and haven't tried on EMR, but on local, it doesn't works and gives an error

Comment: @Xi12 You're going to have to be more clear on exactly what the error is. Does your user you configured with `aws configure` have s3 permissions. I assume this is a corporate account.

Comment: yes, I am the user and have S3 Keys 
If i run the program and specify  below things it works , else it fails

 spark_context._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.s3a.access.key", config.access_id)
    spark_context._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.s3a.secret.key", config.access_key)

Comment: @Xi12 Try it using the `aws s3 cp s3://your-bucket/your_file .` to see if you have the right perms. If you don't post the error we can't help you.

Comment: Yes i can do aws s3 cp... and file copies as expected

Comment: @Xi12 Please edit the question to include the error on local without those lines.

Comment: I have edited the questionn please check

Answer (score 0):

1. The s3a AssumedRoleCredentialProvider uses your current login secrets to call STS.assumeRole and get some short lived credentials for that role
2. you have to make sure that your hadoop binaries are up to date; use hadoop 3.3.1 or higher.
3. you do still have to provide those fs.s3a.access.key and fs.s3a.secret.key values otherwise it can't call assume role
4. and that login must have the permission to call assumeRole on the given role